# Placing swing components one below other using for loop?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, for-loop, flowlayout

```
    //creating two lists of gui components
    ArrayList<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    ArrayList<JTextField> textFieldList = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    //number of labels and textfields i want to add
    int numOfAt = Data.getInstance().getInstances().numAttributes();

    //for loop, for adding these components
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfAt - 1; i++) {
        String name = Data.getInstance().getInstances().attribute(i).name();
        labelList.add(new JLabel(name));
        labelList.get(i).setText(name);

        textFieldList.add(new JTextField());

        add(labelList.get(i));

        add(textFieldList.get(i));
        textFieldList.get(i).setSize(55, 25);
    }
```

These code works. Labels and fields is added on my jPanel. But i can't find solution how to place them one below other. jLabel and jTextField is placed next on each other on the first iteration of for loop. I want on second iteration, next two components to place below first two components. I'm using flow layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using flow layout.

Then you need to use a different layout. One that allows you to display components horizontally and vertically.

The easiest would be a GridLayout, but then all components will be displayed at the same size. Another option is a GridBagLayout which give you more flexibility but is more complex to use.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and experiment with the different layouts to see what you want to use.